# html iframe button now work

Tags: html, iframe

hey this is my html code.
My problem is that the button does not respond.
but when i take off this iframe line code its work just fine..

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fun.js" ></script>
 <style>

 iframe { 
 width: 1000;
 height: 1000;
 position: absolute;
 top:0; left:-20px;
 opacity: 0.5; 
 z-index: 1;
 }

 </head>
 </style>
 <body>
 <div><b>Try to click the green button</b></div>
 </br></br>
 <button id="dis" onclick="fun()">Click here!</button>
 <iframe src="http://www.hit.ac.il" width="500" height="500"></iframe>

 </body>
 </html>
```

and this is the java script function

```
 function fun()
 {
 var button = document.getElementById("dis");
 button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
 var text="hai";
 document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = text;
 }
```

Comment: If you want to be able to click on a button, then don't position stuff - like an iframe - on top of it ... that the kind of advice you're after, or ...?

Comment: Iam trying to make the iframe invisible and when ill click on the button its also click on the iframe inter face

Comment: Well then you gotta go do some research into how to do _click jacking_ properly, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've used the z-index in the first element (iframe) you can use the same for the dic id (#dic).

set z-index to the second level and place it wherever you want it. for example:

```css
 iframe { 
 width: 1000;
 height: 1000;
 position: relative;
 top:0; left:-20px;
 opacity: 0.5; 
 z-index: 1;
 }

 #dis{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     bottom: 50%;
     z-index: 2;
 }
```

of course, as mentioned before, fix the  and  tags position.

Answer (score 0):

Your button doesn't respond, becouse you have set iframe in that position, where you see iframe in top of the button (button is under iframe) and you click on that iframe instead your button.
Try to clear you css iframe's rule and try it again.

You should also change:

```
</head>
</style>
```

to

```
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using javascript to add the iframe [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL99fuhw/22/)

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fun.js" ></script>
 <style>

 iframe { 
 margin-top:100px;
 position: absolute;
 top:0; left:-20px;
 opacity: 0.5; 
 z-index: 1;
 }

 </style>
 <script>


function fun() {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.width = '100%';
  iframe.height = '100%';
  iframe.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  iframe.opacity = '100%';
 }
</script>

 </head>
 <body>



   <div id='button'><b>Do iFrame</b>
   <br><br>
   <button id="dis" onclick="fun()">Click here!</button>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Also note that if you want the iFrame to not look transparent you must change the opacity to something greater than .5 (max of 1)
Additionally if you are trying to make the iframe take up the full screen of the user it is better to use something like width='100%' rather than setting the pixel sizes

Comment: this is not what iam looking for,i need that button to be above the iframe
not call him from function but thx anyway

Comment: Changing answer to better suit your needs, I removed the three lines that deleted the button div and I just added padding above the iframe using CSS which is not the best solution but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

> Please change head and style property

```
<html>
      <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="fun.js" ></script>
      <style>
      iframe { 
      width: 1000;
      height: 1000;
      position: absolute;
      top:0; left:-20px;
      opacity: 0.5; 
      z-index: 1;
      }
    </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div><b>Try to click the green button</b></div>
      </br></br>
      <button id="dis" onclick="fun()">Click here!</button>
      <iframe src="http://www.hit.ac.il" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
     
      </body>
      </html>
```